# Why my ZIP file from NodeJS server is not readable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, zip, jszip

I'm making a web service that will return some **generated zip files** to a client.

Currently I did a really simple code for my test and when I query directly this service the ZIP file is well returned. In a near future, I'll need to pass some parameters through the **header** and so a simple link on the client side will not do the job.

So I decided to use XmlHttpRequest on my client to query the resource and download it as a simple file. The problem comes here, when I generate the download with the server response, the zip file doesn't work.

Here is the NodeJS code (with express) :

```js
.get('/myservice', function(req, res)
{
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/zip');
    const JSZip = require('jszip');

    const zip = new JSZip();
    zip.file('hello.txt', 'Hello world\n');
    zip
        .generateAsync({type: 'nodebuffer'})
        .then(function(content)
        {
            res.send(content)
        }.bind(res));
}
```

Here is the client side Javascript that call the service and then make a file from the answer :

```js
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", "https://mydomain/myservice", false);
    req.send(null);

    function download(filename, text)
    {
        var element = document.createElement('a');
        element.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/zip;charset=base64,' + text);
        element.setAttribute('download', filename);
        element.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        element.click();
        document.body.removeChild(element);
    }

    console.log(req.responseText)
    download('test.zip', req.responseText);
```

I think that I completely miss understand the encoding on the client, but I didn't find the solution.

The downloaded file, when unzip, give me a file that contain the same zip that also do the same thing.

When I call the service with XmlHttpRequest, it is well called and does not throw any error.

I'm using **JSZip** to generate the zip.
I precise that I can't use *blob* on **generateAsync** from JSZip because that throw me an error.

Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to make it so complicated. As you are piping a file already. Just use `window.open('/myservice');` as the browser will handle the fact its a file and keep the current page open and download the file.

https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-euclid-9nkft

Comment: It's look like i can't set headers like I asked with window.open, am I wrong ?

Comment: What headers could you possible need to set with a download? It makes so sense. The only header you ever need to set it file type. Also if you do need extra headers. Set them server side when giving the file.

Comment: I need to set a token header

Comment: Do it serverside then. There is 0 reason to set headers client side unless its setting a header in a request.